# OneTrust Cookie Integration with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cookies, one-trust

My company are running some updates on our cookie policy. We were looking into OneTrust's cookie compliance. It seems to be a popular platform when it comes to Privacy and Security.

We've build our site on Wordpress but mainly work with Elementor Website Builder for the development. Coding skills are very basic. Does anyone know if OneTrust provides a plug-in or if they provide a code that generates a cookie banner with consent and preferences that could be easily inserted to the site?

Is anyone familiar with OneTrust and how the integration works on Wordpress?

Any information would help.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you have set up Google Tag Manager for website then you can use GTM for script integration. Otherwise add the script to the  section before any other script.
Plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-headers-and-footers/